# Hibernate Envers: AuditQuery throws ClasscastException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers, audit-tables

I have a basic entity called **Report**, which is annotated with **@Audited** annotation. Changes to the entity are being stored in the database correctly by envers, where I have a number of revisions for the Report entity ID 1.

The following code is being used by my DAO class to retrieve a a list of all revisions from the audit table:

```
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
AuditQuery query = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Report.class, true, true);
query.add(AuditEntity.id().eq(1);
List<Object[]> auditList = query.getResultList();
```

The last line in this code snippet throws the following exception, and I can't seem to figure out why:

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity_$$_javassist_2 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxy(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:148)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:73)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:758)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4419)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:333)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:259)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1017)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:944)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:671)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:489)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:667)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:835)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:949)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:917)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2548)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2534)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2364)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2359)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1194)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.buildAndExecuteQuery(AbstractAuditQuery.java:100)
at org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.list(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:112)
at org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractAuditQuery.java:110)
at com.nordea.cms.art.cto.reporting.spring.dao.ReportsDao.getReportVersions(ReportsDao.java:137)
at com.nordea.cms.art.cto.reporting.spring.dao.ReportsDao$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ce386fbe.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
at com.nordea.cms.art.cto.reporting.spring.dao.ReportsDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7b386dc3.getReportVersions(<generated>)
at com.nordea.cms.art.cto.reporting.spring.service.ReportsService.getReportVersions(ReportsService.java:80)
at com.nordea.cms.art.cto.reporting.spring.controllers.ReportsController.showReports(ReportsController.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3363)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

Could anybody help explain why that might be the case?

**Versions being used**:

- Spring 3.2.3
- Hibernate 4.2.8
- Hibernate-envers 4.2.8
- javassist 3.18.1-GA

Comment: i think you need to pass other values into the forRevisionsOfEntity query. As far as i remember, one of the booleans determines the return type (Entity / Array of Objects)

Comment: And a full stack trace is always helpful

Comment: @adamw Amended with full stack trace.

Comment: @aumand: I've tried with various boolean pairs, all of them give the same result. Interestingly enough calling auditReader.getRevisions(Report.class, 1) gives me a list of revision numbers, which matches that which I can see in my audit table. 

I don't seem to be able to fetch the actual entities themselves, though.

Comment: I dont have the ability to test right now. I am still convinced that there is something wrong with that api call. If not solved until monday, i'll have a look at it..

Comment: @aumand still the same issue. If you are able to test, that would be great. In this case let us assume that Report.class is annotated as Audited and has a field called private int id which is annotated by the Id tag.

Comment: My assumption was wrong - the parameters you passed into were correct. I created a minimal example using the latest version of hibernate envers. There the code worked as expected. I changed to the mentioned version 4.2.8 and it is still ok. Can you verify that this sample works within your code? 
http://pastebin.com/Ca3dAyDP (Report is Audited and has a text and an id property)

EDIT: I am using the JPA and MYSQL in this example, but as your DB connection seems ok, you can replace the first lines again to use your current session.

Comment: @aumand thanks for the suggestion. The only difference in my current implementation to your suggested solution is that I am using SessionFactory and a session to initialize my AuditReader instead of the EntityManagerFactory (because my Spring implementation is configured in this way using XML). 

Would you be able to test using SessionFactory instead? I haven't tried configuring an EntityManager in the past.